# Free mapping component for IOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, mapkit, openstreetmap

Today I have realized, that IOS MapKit must not be used for vehicle tracking apps, just if you have google premium (10 000 dollars/yeer/100 vehicles, so it is far from ideal for me)

So my question is if there are any good and free mapping component (e.g. open street based) for IOS that can be used free also in vehicle tracking applications?

Thanks

Comment: Tom, maybe you should check, how bounties work. You wasted 300 points for offering them, but nobody received them. http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties

Comment: I know but i did not get the answers...thanks

Answer (score 2):

[ESRI has a free IOS control](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/smartphones/develop.html).  it can talk to their public servers or to a private server.

[here is a "list" of the free services](http://www.esri.com/data/free-data/index.html) offered by ESRI.  You should check them out and see if any of them meet your needs.  I don't know how good their coverage of Europe is.

Comment: Thanks, but as I think they don't have free, detailed worldwide maps.

Comment: they have public servers that cover the whole world.  map details/coverage vary according to the area, tho.

Comment: What about Europe? Do they have a street level one like Google? I could not find this public servers. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't know about street-level coverage in Europe, if you look at their public examples/demos (esp the silverlight ones where they show you the code) the server addresses are right there for anyone to see.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [route-me](https://github.com/route-me/route-me) project for showing maps on iOS devices. It can show online and offline maps. If you need routing check out [this forum thread](http://forum.openstreetmap.org/viewtopic.php?id=735). I haven't tested it, but as far as I understood, you can calculate routes on your server and then give them back to you iOS app.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [CloudMade](http://cloudmade.com/products/iphone-sdk) and their [NaviStudio](http://developers.cloudmade.com/projects/show/navi-studio). By reading this [overview](http://cloudmade.com/select/mobile), I understand, that it is free, but may contain advertisement.